# How to get access to parent form?

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0

I have two Windows Form in project C#.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public void add(){
       // 
    }
}

public partial class FormAdd : Form
{
   //
}
```

In `Form1` after button click I open `FormAdd`:

```
var form = new FormAdd();
            form.Show();
```

After in `FormAdd` I try to call parent method `add`:

```
Form1 f = new Form1();
f.add();
```

But I can not get access to any methods and properties of parent form.

I get error:

[image]

Comment: The error means that your lines of code are not **inside** the Forms code.  Most likely you've got mismatched brackets.  Also, you should always put code inside `if` statements inside their own blocks.  That `position = 0` line is a bug waiting to happen.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to pass Form1 in as the Owner of your FormAdd instance in the Show() call:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var form = new FormAdd();
        form.Show(this); // pass this instance of Form1 in as the Owner of our FormAdd instance
    }

}
```

Now, over in FormAdd, cast the Owner property to Form1 and call add():

```
public partial class FormAdd : Form
{

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.Owner is Form1)
        {
            Form1 f1 = (Form1)this.Owner;
            f1.add();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you, but how to get acess to public variable in Form1?

Comment: ?...the same way I demonstrated that you could access the **public** method `add()` in Form1.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your picture, try to add the code above one bracket. Since the error seems to be on the scope of your condition.

This should look like this:

```
else 
   position = 0;
 //{  <-- Remove this and put it below
   if (this.Owner is Form1)
   {
      //TODO:
   }
  }  //This should be here
```

Everything should compile properly after that.